# QuickBooks 2010 w/ iCal

Tags: macos, mac, finance, calendar.app, quickbooks

Whenever I select item from "Memorized Transaction List" and then check box "Show in iCal", and then "OK", it won't remember that and nothing appears in iCal. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fyi: the only work around I found so far is to re-create invoice with this feature enabled.